# Parsing and editing a unity animation clip with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

So I've managed to create a custom editor window that select an animation clip and  reads all of its text into a string. Now i need to parse the string to find out the curve count and curveMapping so I can create a new file that overrides the values. The parts of the string I'm interested in look like this :

```
 m_PPtrCurves:
  - curve:
    - time: 0
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    - time: 0.6
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: ae9111d826eb24442b21523b30b748bd, type: 3}
    - time: 0.6666667
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 88840e4f59c4a6040922d9b6eed3dec3, type: 3}
    - time: 1.2333333
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 88840e4f59c4a6040922d9b6eed3dec3, type: 3}
    - time: 2.0001667
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: ae9111d826eb24442b21523b30b748bd, type: 3}
    - time: 2.05
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    - time: 3.1166666
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 502fc97a961e4424ea008c0e546c83ef, type: 3}
    - time: 3.45
      value: {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    attribute: m_Sprite
    path: 
    classID: 114
    script: {fileID: -765806418, guid: f5f67c52d1564df4a8936ccd202a3bd8, type: 3}
```

And :

```
 pptrCurveMapping:
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: ae9111d826eb24442b21523b30b748bd, type: 3}
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: 88840e4f59c4a6040922d9b6eed3dec3, type: 3}
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: 88840e4f59c4a6040922d9b6eed3dec3, type: 3}
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: ae9111d826eb24442b21523b30b748bd, type: 3}
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: 502fc97a961e4424ea008c0e546c83ef, type: 3}
    - {fileID: 21300000, guid: 1fa82f3b0bb4e1f49ab9a9ffd4e891b1, type: 3}
```

Now  I will be completely honest. I don't know anything about RegEx or how to construct it to help me in this case. First I need to count the curves to generate the appropriate number of items in my custom windows and then I need to replace the guid value of each curve with a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a YAML file, don't try to parse it with Regex, it'll create an unmaintainable mess.

Add something like [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet) and access it via a simple, readable object oriented interface and not messy lines of regex (Note: I've not used YamlDotNet, my YAML experience is in python)

(I've tested the file with http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ to double check its format, parses perfectly fine)